# Is these possible synchronisation of two tables first handle the request from php and second from magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

if php table value change then also update the magento table. FrontEnd is any thing its website or something else.

Comment: Can't uderstand your questions please explain with detail and provide more info

Comment: i have a shopping website ...suppose a buyer purchase some this from website.. there must some changes in my stock table..now i want to know that there is any way or extension which can help me to sync the same in magento table

Comment: @murtuza i just want inventory synchronisation

Comment: You have another website Not in magento? and you want to sync with magento

Comment: @murtuza yes its not in magento ....i have local phpmyadmin database there is table inside named product i just want to sync this table with magento

Comment: Use magento API For sync purposes

Comment: which one ...can u provide me the link

Answer (score 0):

You can use below API for your inventory Purpose ,

This API shows how to use Magento API and may solve your purpose

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/Inventory.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.list.html

Comment: Please guide me how to use this API. because after full study we can't find the way from where we start this API concept.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Comment: Have you try these api's

Comment: no ...actually am new in magento and facing soo many problems ...recenty am used this( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0oNhw-4RG0 ) but its showing page is not working